# Creating key value pairs from file

Tags: python

I have the following script that reads the entire `file.bin` file, how do I amend to read the first 1000 lines of the file instead? Thanks.

```
with open("file.bin","r") as text:
    for line in text:
        if line.startswith('MH =') or line.startswith('MN ='):
            value, key = line.strip().split('=')
            res[key] = value
            if num < 1000:
                print '%s : %s' % (key, value)
            num = num + 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your num reaches 1000, break;

```
ctr = 0;
for line in text:
    ctr = ctr + 1
    if ctr > 1000:
        break
    if line.startswith('MH =') or line.startswith('MN ='):
        value, key = line.strip().split('=')
        res[key] = value
        if num < 1000:
            print '%s : %s' % (key, value)
        num = num + 1
```

Comment: I find that the num < 1000 indicates the number of MH = or MN = instead of the first 1000 lines processed. Whats wrong with the script?

Comment: @Brendan: If you want it the other way, outdent `num = num + 1`.  It could also be simplified to `num += 1`.  I would suggest putting `if num >= 1000: break` above the `if line.startswith...` block so that `print '%s...` doesn't need to be in an `if` block.

Comment: I actually intend to write a script that process the first 1000 lines of the .bin file and capture lines starting with MH = or MN = as key value pairs. But the script now turned out to capture the first 1000 MH = or MN = instead.

Comment: @PriyanshGoel I guess you could delete the references to `num`, otherwise it's a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different take on the existing answer:

```
for i, line in enumerate(text):
    if i == 1000:
        break
    if line.startswith('MH =') or line.startswith('MN ='):
        value, key = line.strip().split('=')
        res[key] = value
        print '%s : %s' % (key, value)
```

Maybe an overkill for this case, but useful to know is the 'islice' function 'itertools' which would allow you to do the following:

```
from itertools import islice

for line in islice(text, 1000):
    # ...
```

Also, off-topic but you could do (among other things like using regexp):

```
line.startswith(('MH =', 'MN ='))
```

instead of

```
line.startswith('MH =') or line.startswith('MN =')
```